# FluentNHibernate - Issue with HasMany reference of a subclass class where the References is in the parent class

Tags: c#, inheritance, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I would like to reference both a parent class and its subclass, but I have an issue with the structure bellow. NHibernate generates the reference column in both the parent table and the child table.

```
public class Container{
    public virtual IEnumerable<SomeClass> SomeClasses {get;set;}
    public virtual IEnumerable<SomeSubClass> SomeSubClasses {get;set;}
}

public class SomeClass{
    public virtual Container Container {get;set;}
    ...
}

public class SomeSubClass: SomeClass{
    ...
}

public class ContainerMap: ClassMap<Container>{
    public ContainerMap(){
        Table("Container");
        ...
        HasMany(x => x.SomeClasses)
                .KeyColumn("ContainerID")
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
                .LazyLoad()
                .Inverse()
                .AsBag();

            HasMany(x => x.SomeSubClasses)
                .KeyColumn("ContainerID")
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
                .LazyLoad()
                .Inverse()
                .AsBag();
        ...
    }
}

public class SomeClassMap: ClassMap<SomeClass>{
    public SomeClassMap(){
        Table("Parent");
        ...
        References(x => x.Container, "ContainerID").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        ...
    }
}
public class SomeSubClassMap: SubclassMap<SomeClass>{
    public SomeSubClassMap(){
        Table("Child");
        ...
    }
}
```

The only way I found as a workaround is to specify the mapping like so:

```
HasMany<SomeClass>(x => x.SomeSubClasses)
                .KeyColumn("ContainerID")
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
                .LazyLoad()
                .Inverse()
                .AsBag();
```

With that, NHibernate won't generate the ContainerID column in the child table, but I get an exception when loading a container with both IEnumerable populated. Exception:

System.ArgumentException : The value "Models.SomeClass" is not of type "Models.SomeSubClass" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
Parameter name: value

How do I map this structure properly?